# Postgresql select until certain total amount is reached

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I was wondering if I could get any help with the following problem.

I have a table of transactions (simplified below) and I only want to select transactions until my amount total reaches a certain amount.

`Transactions` table

```
 id |   date   | amount 
----|----------|--------
 1  | 1/1/2012 |   2 
 2  | 2/1/2012 |   3 
 3  | 3/1/2012 |   4
 4  | 4/1/2012 |   20 
 5  | 5/1/2012 |   1 
 6  | 6/1/2012 |   2
```

Now say I want to do a select on the table until the amount total is 6 i.e just the first 2 rows, how would I do this?

I was thinking of maybe doing a join with itself and some sum but not really getting anywhere. I'd prefer no to use any functions if possible.

Also anything similar for minimum amount.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

T

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
select id, 
       date, 
       amount, 
       running_total
from (
    select id,
           date,
           amount,
           sum(amount) over (order by date asc) as running_total
    from transactions
) t
where running_total <= 6
```

Comment: Decided to use this. THANKS :)

Comment: Think there might be a slight problem with this.
If I try the new transactions table above with a running_total<= 15 I will still only get the trans id 1,2,3 and not 5,6.
Any help with that?

Comment: my current solution is to (order by amount asc, date asc)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can you please show how can I alter this SQL to get the list of `id`'s and `running_total` that will be greater than 8. So for given example of `transactions` table i need to get minimum rows that in sum will give me amount > 8, ordered by date (it needs to return `id`'s 1,2,3, as they will return 9 in total)?

Comment: This returns duplicate rows for me. Although I'm using `sqlite`.

Answer (score 1):

```
select T1.*
from Transactions as T1
where 6 - (select sum(T2.amount) 
               from Transactions as T2 where  T2.id <= T1.id
          ) >= 0
order by id asc
```

This query works on SQL Server if Postgres supports subqueries like SQL Server does it can help you

Comment: @amount_to_rich is not an expression is just a paramameter to be replaced by the amount to rich, i edited my post

Comment: try it before i said that it works on sqlserver i'm not sure it will work on postgres

Comment: Without the parameter it should run just fine on PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1):

Although it may not be the most efficent way (as you're still, in essence, selecting everything first), I'd look at using a running total.

Something like:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  (
  SELECT
    id
    , date
    , amount
    , (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM Transactions WHERE id <= t.id) AS RunningTotal
  FROM
    Transactions t
) t1
WHERE
  t1.RunningTotal < 6
```

Comment: You are assuming that the ids are in the same order as the date which might not necessarily be the case.

Comment: Yeah, if the date is a concern there would need to be an order by in the subquery, but that isn't mentioned in the opening post (unless it's just implied - as it would make sense!).