# Postgresql / PostGIS, calculating a running total until a certain amount while ordering on calculated column

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, postgis

I have a query very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10549327/postgresql-select-until-certain-total-amount-is-reached) where I'm creating a running total until I reach a certain value. In my case, I'm counting population of counties until I reach the desired population.

I want to order the search by the distance to a lng/lat, however, so that I add counties that are closest first. I'm running this query below but I get no results. When I instead do `ORDER BY row_id` or any non-SPATIALLY-calculated column, it comes back with results. I've also tried it using two `WITH` clauses but I still get no results. I've tried casting `distance` as integer since maybe it wasn't typed properly but that didn't help.

I've set up a test server where you can run queries with this endpoint
`http://sqltestmcr.cartodb.com/api/v2/sql?q=<your query statement here>`

This is the query that I am trying. Below are variations that work.
You can see the results of this query with this link:
`http://sqltestmcr.cartodb.com/api/v2/sql?q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20(%20SELECT%20county,%20the_geom,%20distance,%20row_id_2,%20sum(population)%20over%20(order%20by%20distance%20asc)%20as%20running_total%20FROM%20(%20SELECT%20row_id,%20county,%20population,%20the_geom,%20row_id%20*%202%20AS%20row_id_2,%20ST_Distance(%20ST_Centroid(the_geom),%20ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-72.1235%2042.3521)',%204326)%20)%20AS%20distance%20FROM%20counties_ny_export)%20sq1)%20sq2%20WHERE%20running_total%20%3C=%201400`

```
    SELECT
    *
    FROM (
        SELECT 
        county,
        the_geom,
        distance,
        row_id_2,
        sum(population) over (order by distance asc) as running_total
      FROM (
        SELECT 
        row_id,
        county, 
        population,
        the_geom,
        row_id * 2 AS row_id_2,
        ST_Distance(
          ST_Centroid(the_geom), 
          ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-72.1235 42.3521)', 4326)
        ) AS distance 
        FROM
        counties_ny_export
    ) sq1
    ) sq2   
    where running_total <= 1400
```

The following two queries works where I set `ORDER BY row_id` or `ORDER BY row_id_2`
Test link with `row_id`:
`http://sqltestmcr.cartodb.com/api/v2/sql?q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20(%20SELECT%20county,%20the_geom,%20distance,%20row_id_2,%20sum(population)%20over%20(order%20by%20row_id%20asc)%20as%20running_total%20FROM%20(%20SELECT%20row_id,%20county,%20population,%20the_geom,%20row_id%20*%202%20AS%20row_id_2,%20ST_Distance(%20ST_Centroid(the_geom),%20ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-72.1235%2042.3521)',%204326)%20)%20AS%20distance%20FROM%20counties_ny_export)%20sq1)%20sq2%20WHERE%20running_total%20%3C=%201400`

```
    SELECT
    *
    FROM (
        SELECT 
        county,
        the_geom,
        distance,
        row_id_2,
        sum(population) over (order by row_id asc) as running_total
      FROM (
        SELECT 
        row_id,
        county, 
        population,
        the_geom,
        row_id * 2 AS row_id_2,
        ST_Distance(
          ST_Centroid(the_geom), 
          ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-72.1235 42.3521)', 4326)
        ) AS distance 
        FROM
        counties_ny_export
    ) sq1
    ) sq2   
    where running_total <= 1400
```

Test link with `row_id_2`:
`http://sqltestmcr.cartodb.com/api/v2/sql?q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20(%20SELECT%20county,%20the_geom,%20distance,%20row_id_2,%20sum(population)%20over%20(order%20by%20row_id_2%20asc)%20as%20running_total%20FROM%20(%20SELECT%20row_id,%20county,%20population,%20the_geom,%20row_id%20*%202%20AS%20row_id_2,%20ST_Distance(%20ST_Centroid(the_geom),%20ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-72.1235%2042.3521)',%204326)%20)%20AS%20distance%20FROM%20counties_ny_export)%20sq1)%20sq2%20WHERE%20running_total%20%3C=%201400`

Comment: If you can provide some sample on [SQLFiddel](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1) then it will be much easier to solve your problem

Comment: SQL Fiddle doesn't have PostGIS capabilities and PostGIS seems to be the problem since other, non-spatially-computed column values work. Instead, I've created a test database you can query through the endpoints above. You can see the full data with `http://sqltestmcr.cartodb.com/api/v2/sql?q=SELECT * FROM counties_ny_export`. Queries needn't be URI-encoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is working fine, it just happens that the closest county to the query point has a population of 1700 and thus exceeds the running total cut-off.

Raising the running total cut-off to 5000 ([query](http://sqltestmcr.cartodb.com/api/v2/sql?q=SELECT%20%2a%20FROM%20%28%20SELECT%20county,%20population,%20distance,%20row_id_2,%20sum%28population%29%20over%20%28order%20by%20distance%20asc%29%20as%20running_total%20FROM%20%28%20SELECT%20row_id,%20county,%20population,%20the_geom,%20row_id%20%2a%202%20AS%20row_id_2,%20ST_Distance%28%20ST_Centroid%28the_geom%29,%20ST_GeomFromText%28%27POINT%28-72.1235%2042.3521%29%27,%204326%29%20%29%20AS%20distance%20FROM%20counties_ny_export%29%20sq1%29%20sq2%20WHERE%20running_total%20%3C=%205000)) selects two rows:

```
{'fields': {'county': {'type': 'string'},
            'distance': {'type': 'number'},
            'population': {'type': 'number'},
            'row_id_2': {'type': 'number'},
            'running_total': {'type': 'number'}},
 'rows': [{'county': 'Rensselaer',
           'distance': 1.4299124873995,
           'population': 1700,
           'row_id_2': 34,
           'running_total': 1700},
          {'county': 'Columbia',
           'distance': 1.51173290729954,
           'population': 2200,
           'row_id_2': 44,
           'running_total': 3900}],
 'time': 0.002,
 'total_rows': 2}
```

Similarly, if you have a different query point that is closest to a county with < 1400, then there should be 1 or more rows returned.