# PostgreSQL, select rows until certain amount is reached and exceeded

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table with `id`,`date` and `amount`, i need to get the list,of `id`'s, ordered by date DESC, that in total to be greater or equal than some specific value.

```
 id |   date   | amount 
----|----------|--------
 1  | 1/1/2017 |   3 
 2  | 2/1/2017 |   5 
 3  | 3/1/2017 |   4
 4  | 4/1/2017 |   2 
 5  | 5/1/2017 |   7 
 6  | 6/1/2017 |   4
```

For example

1. I need to get all rows that in total will be >= 12, ORDER BY date DESC. Then it's going to be 3 rows: 6, 5, 4, as 4+7+2 = 13.
2. I need to get all rows that in total will be >= 5, ORDER BY date DESC. Then it's going to be 2 rows: 6, 5 as 4+7 = 11.
3. I need to get all rows that in total will be >= 15, ORDER BY date DESC. Then it's going to be 4 rows: 6, 5, 4, 3 as 4+7+2+4 = 17.

*There is a very similar question and solution [Postgresql select until certain total amount is reached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10549327/postgresql-select-until-certain-total-amount-is-reached/10550007) but I need a bit different.*

Thanks for any help.

Comment: how is it different from the linked question?

Comment: @vkp the linked question takes all rows that are **less** than given value, i need more rows, to exceed given value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, sum(amount) over (order by date desc) as running_amount
      from t
     ) t
where running_amount - amount < 12
order by date desc;
```

Comment: should be `running_amount - amount < 12` to not include an extra row when the running amount exactly equals sum of n rows.

Comment: @vkp yes, you're right, with `<` results won't have extra row. Thank you both for you help, exactly what I needed