# postgres typeorm return untill sum of a column is greater than condition

Tags: postgresql, aggregation, typeorm

I have an entity which has a column type bigint named price.

It is a very large table. I want to get data from this table until the price is greater than or equal to a number.

How can I achieve that without getting the entire table from result

```js
@Entity()
export class myTable extends BaseEntity {
  @Column({type:"bigint})
  price:number
}
```

I want to get entities until the sum of the prices are greater than or equal to a number

```js
const input: number = 50000
const result = await myTable.find(/*order by date and where sum (price) >= input*/)
```

What is the syntax and how can I do this? using baseEntity query or queryBuilder and preferably not the raw query result

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to create a raw query using the [query builder](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/select-query-builder.md#what-is-querybuilder) for this. You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10549327/postgresql-select-until-certain-total-amount-is-reached) regarding the query.

Comment: I have the query bellow:

`SELECT *
from (
  SELECT *,  
  sum(price) over (order by datel asc) as total
    from orders
) t
where total <= 20000

However, this has a bug which I do not understand. the total column for the second row is the same as third row, even though it has a value. I mean the total field for the second row is the third row, but it should be less!!
and if the total is less than the first total, it returns null, but I want to have the first row so the user can buy some portion of the merchandise.

Do you know how I can solve this?

Comment: I am not able to understand what you want to convey

Comment: Imagine I have 2000$, the orders price orderdBy date are: 5k, 3k,10k, 4k, 12k, etc. I only want to return up to 4k, cause after that is more than the user can buy. How do I do it?
`SELECT * from 
( SELECT *, sum(price) over (order by datel asc) as total from orders ) t
 where total <= 20000`
does not return what I want. cause it returns empty for anything lower than the first price. what query you think is best to write here to optimize my query?